# Simultaneous validateAsync fails in Loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

In my project I'm running a validate function to prevent double bookings:

```
Booking.validateAsync('double_booking', checkDoubleBooking, {
  message: 'Can\'t set dates because there is already another booking on those dates'
});

function checkDoubleBooking(error, done) {
var _this = this;

if (!this.propertyId || !this.start || !this.end) {
  done();
  return;
}

function filter(obj) {

  var filters = [];
  filters.push({
    propertyId: obj.propertyId
  });
  filters.push({
    or: [{
      start: {
        between: [obj.start, obj.end]
      }
    }, {
      end: {
        between: [obj.start, obj.end]
      }
    }, {
      and: [{
        start: {
          lte: obj.start
        }
      }, {
        end: {
          gte: obj.end
        }
      }]
    }
      // start is before and end is after
    ]
  });
  filters.push({
    cancelled_at: null
  });
  //
  // only push object filter to filters when there is an
  //obj.id e.g. when editing a booking.
  //
  if (obj.id) {
    filters.push({
      id: {
        neq: obj.id
      }
    });
  }
  return filters;
}

Booking.find({
  where: {
    and: filter(this)
  }
}, function (err, doubleBooking) {
  if (doubleBooking && doubleBooking[0]) {
    error();
    done();
  } else {
    done();
  }
});
}
```

However, I found that it fails when multiple bookings are made simultaneously and I can add double bookings like in the following script:

```
var app = require(require('path').resolve(__dirname, './server/server.js'));
var async = require('async');
var debug = require('debug')('iambnb:validationracetest');

var Booking = app.models.Booking;

var bookingdata = {
  propertyId: 511,
  start: "2016-08-18T07:14:53+00:00",
  end: "2016-08-21T07:14:53+00:00",
  cleaning:"2016-08-21T07:14:53+00:00"
}

var testBooking = new Booking(bookingdata);

async.parallel([
    function(callback){
      testBooking.save(function(err, result){
        if (err) {
          debug(err)
        }
        callback(result)
      })
     },
    function(callback){
      testBooking.save(function(err, result){
        if (err) {
          debug(err)
        }
        callback(result);
      })
     }
],function(err, result){
  if (err) {
    debug(err);
  }

  debug('result: ', JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

Comment: If you ran into a bug, please post on [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues)!

Comment: Thanks, I posted it in the Issues. Still curious if others ran into this problem or maybe have a suggestion for a solution.

Comment: Can I get the link to the issue?

Comment: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/2653